# как сделать проверку в mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Использую redbean php.
пользователь ставит лайк, это записывается в бд таблицу 'post'
так же есть общая таблица 'user2like' куда записывается id поста и id
 пользователя
структура user2like

> id
>
> user_id
>
> post_id

не могу понять как проверить что пользователь поставил лайк определенному посту
Пытался проверять но получается что он всем постам ставит как определенное

цикл

```
    foreach ( $pjk as $posting ) {

$like=R::findOne('user2like', 'post_id = ? AND user_id=?', array($posting['id'], $_SESSION['logged_user']->id));

                    if (/*не могу понять как проверить*/)

        {
            $l= 'вы уже поставили' ;
        }           
                echo '<div class="col-auto" id="text_posting_user" data-id="'.$posting['id'].'" style="padding: 1.7em; padding-bottom: 0;">

                    <div class="text_p"><p>'.$posting['post'].'</p></div>
                    <hr style="margin-bottom: 0.5rem;">
                    <div class="b_funk_post">
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td><div class="like" data-id="'.$posting['id'].'">'.$posting['like'].'</div>'.$l.'</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
             }
```

Comment: Не знаю как в вашем средстве общения с БД задавать несколько условий, но вам надо искать запись `post_id=? and user_id=?` ...

Comment: if (R::findOne('user2like', 'post_id = ? AND user_id=?', array($posting['id'], $_SESSION['logged_user']->id)) )  не помогло все равно выводит даже на тех записях где лайк не ставил

Comment: Тогда вместо надписи выведите то, что вам функция findOne вернула. Может тогда станет понятно что она такое возвращает, что условие считается истинным

Comment: $like=R::findOne('user2like', 'post_id = ? AND user_id=?', array($posting['id'], $_SESSION['logged_user']->id));      
     $l = $like;     так выводит массив данных, и выводит именно там где лайк поставлен,  как условие сделать? если делаю условие то отображается на всех записях и на тех где не ставил лайк

Answer (score 0):

Может поможет кому. извиняюсь за корявость

```
    foreach ( $pjk as $posting ) {

                echo '<div class="col-auto" id="text_posting_user" data-id="'.$posting['id'].'" style="padding: 1.7em; padding-bottom: 0;">

                    <div class="text_p"><p>'.$posting['post'].'</p></div>
                    <hr style="margin-bottom: 0.5rem;">
                    <div class="b_funk_post">
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td><div class="like" data-id="'.$posting['id'].'">'.$posting['like'].'</div>';
                if(R::findOne('user2like', 'post_id = ? AND user_id=?', array($posting['id'], $_SESSION['logged_user']->id))){
                echo 'уже нажимали';       
                        }
echo  '</td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    </div>
                    </div>';
             }
```